# Incrementing a pointer by a large value give unexpected output?

Tags: c++, memory

I was studying pointers and came across a concept called pointer arithmetic. It said you can jump from one memory address to another by simply incrementing the address of the pointer.

I do understand that when we increment the address by 1, we are simply moving ahead by size of 4 bytes. But I wanted to see if I just increment the pointer to a random huge value, which number will I get in return?

[image: output]

Well, the output was confusing. It returned a memory address, but it did not print the value.

Why did I even get an output? Why did the program not crash?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
// *pointer arithmetic

    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    cout << arr << endl; // this prints an address

    int *newPtr = arr; // hence this means pointer has address of first element of the array
    cout << "Allocation of the array is as follows: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int); i++)
    {
        cout << newPtr << endl;
        newPtr++; // pointer shifts to next element of the array
    }
    newPtr += 1293893847;
    cout << "Address of random pointer is " << newPtr << endl;
    cout << "Value of random pointer is " << *newPtr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: the program did crash, your last output line wasn't printed.

Comment: If a pointer points at an element of an array you can use pointer arithmetic to get at other elements of the array. If the pointer doesn't point at an element of an array or if pointer arithmetic would create a pointer that points outside the array all bets are off. (unless the pointer is one past the end of the array, which is what `newPtr++` does the last time through the `for` loop).

Comment: `int *pt` is a pointer to type `int`, which usually is size of 4-bytes. Incrementing such pointer moves it 4 bytes, same as the size of the pointer. For `char *pt` its size is 1, so incrementing goes only 1 byte ahead. Don't confuse the size of type the pointer points to, with the size of the pointer itself, which is 4/8 bytes according to the type of OS (32/64 bits)

Comment: @Ripi2 -- yes, if the size of a pointer is 4 bytes.

Comment: This is Undefined Behavior (UB) - derefencing pointer past-the-end of the array. The only thing you could do is construct pointer, the "one past-the-end", and that is it.

Comment: Also, your "random huge value", multiplied by 4, caused the memory address to wrap around.

Comment: Praise whatever deities you worship when you get a visible crash. A crash is a sure sign you have a bug. Getting the result you expected is not. C++ follows a philosophy of not performing and charging for services you did not request. Checking a pointer dereference, when it is possible to do so, has a cost, so C++ does not perform such a check unless you request it because that test would be a performance penalty for all programs that did not make the same mistake. C++ gives great power, but with great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: thanks guys, I will keep undefined behaviour in mind. I did not realise the program had crashed. I'm used to node.js spitting out errors before crashing... well I mean g++ does that too but... not in this case? Guess its just undefined behaviour then

Comment: Undefined Behaviour can do anything. Be glad no one knocked at your door looking for [Sarah Connor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terminator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add 1 to a pointer, the pointer increases by the size of the type it is a pointer to, possibly 4 in the case of an `int`.

When doing pointer math, care must be taken to ensure the pointer continues to point to valid memory locations. Because otherwise, you are likely to crash your program when you attempt to access the memory at that location.

Adding random numbers to a pointer is a mistake, and when you try and access the memory at the new location, you will be very lucky if your app doesn't just crash. Don't do this.